# Restore the UI-state after recreating the fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-lifecycle

How can I restore the UI status of my Fragment-A after I have replaced it with Fragment-B and then call Fragment-A again?

Comment: You need to be more specific about whether `replace` was also followed by an `addToBackStack` or not.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce yes, the `replace` is followed by `addToBackStack`. I want for example to open a `SettingsFragment` and If I go back to `HomeFragment` I want the same UI-State there as previously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use SharedViewModel between these two fragments and store the state there.

[Share data between fragments with SharedViewModel](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#sharing)

Comment: This answer is complete only if we consider the addition of `SavedStateHandle` from `viewmodel-savedstate`, and the `SharedViewModel` stores/retrieves its state from the `SavedStateHandle` that it gets from the `AbstractSavedStateViewModelFactory`.

Comment: @MakinTosH This is a good idea, but if I replace a fragment, it will be start at onCreate and the ViewModel will be cleared. Or am I wrong?

Comment: SharedViewModel is scoped to acitivity so it's not being cleared when fragment is destroyed. `viewModel = activity?.run {
            ViewModelProviders.of(this)[SharedViewModel::class.java]
        } ?: throw Exception("Invalid Activity")`